# MEX cuda code with dynamic parallelism - unable to compile

Tags: matlab, cuda, mex

I have a code by name mexCodeCuda.cu which uses dynamic parallelism. In the matlab interface, when I try to execute the following commands, I get the following error :

```
system('nvcc --compile mexCodeCuda.cu -o mexCodeCuda.o --compiler-options -fPIC -m64 -rdc=true -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -O3 -lineinfo -use_fast_math -lcudadevrt -I/cm/shared/apps/MATLAB/extern/include')

system('nvcc -arch=sm_35 -dlink mexCodeCuda.o -o dlink.o')

eval('mex mexCodeCuda.o dlink.o -L'CUDA_LIB_PATH '-lcudart')
```

It gives the following error :

```
Error using mex
/usr/bin/ld: dlink.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `__nv_module_id' can
not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
dlink.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can anyone help me ?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Did you try rerunning `mex` and the other `nvcc` with `-fPIC`?

Comment: When I added -fPIC to the second nvcc, it raised an error 
nvcc fatal : Unknown option 'fPIC'
Running with mex throws the following error: 
Unknown MEX argument '-fPIC'.

Comment: When you added -fPIC to the second nvcc, did you actually do `--compiler-options -fPIC`

Comment: After adding --compiler-options -fPIC to the second nvcc, it compiled but when I run eval(without fPIC inside eval) it throws an error :

Error using mex
dlink.o: In function `__cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_65_tmpxft_00007d13_00000000_9_cuda_device_runtime_compute_50_cpp1_ii_5f6993ef':
link.stub:(.text+0xab): undefined reference to `__fatbinwrap_65_tmpxft_00007d13_00000000_9_cuda_device_runtime_compute_50_cpp1_ii_5f6993ef'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: I suspect you need to specify the `cudadevrt` runtime option on the `mex` command, just as you have with the first `nvcc` call. And you may need to add `-fPIC` to the mex linking via `LDCXXFLAGS` or `LDFLAGS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few changes:

- Add `-fPIC` to the second `nvcc` command (using `--compiler-options`, just as you did with the first `nvcc`).
- Specify the `cudadevrt` runtime option on the `mex` command (`-lcudadevrt`), just as you have with the first `nvcc` call.
- And you *may* need to add `-fPIC` to the mex linking via `LDCXXFLAGS` or `LDFLAGS`. Not sure.

Comment: Adding -lcudadevrt to the mex command resulted in successful compilation of the mex code. Adding -fPIC was not necessary for the mex compilation.  Thanks a lot.